# Returning n times the nth number of different lists in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary that resembles this :

```
[{ 'key' : 10, 'values' : [ [1,2] [3,4,5] [6,7,8,9] ] }, { ... }]
```

I'm trying to return new dictionaries with 'intersection' as key and the nth element of each list as values for as long as there are values in the longest list. The lists being of different lengths, the shorter ones would just have their last values appended multiple times, such as this :

```
{10:[1,3,6]}

{10:[2,4,7]}

{10:[2,5,8]}

{10:[2,5,9]}
```

should I iterate as itervalues(), iterkey(), or iteritems()?
There might be a similar question posted but I can't find a way to explain concisely, I'm lacking keywords.

How do I make a function that would complete that task?

Comment: Is that you fill expected output?

Comment: Also what is *intersection*?

Comment: @Cunningham the output would be the series of dictionaries with the value of 'key' as key. 'intersection' is just the actual string I'm using for my own code instead of 'key'. (the integers are actually Qgis Points derived from Multi-lines of different lengths. But I felt like they were keeping from the clarity of the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **iterate as many times as there are items in the longest list of numbers**. In every iteration you use the incremental index to get the nth value out of every list.

Try something like this:

```
def intersect(key,values):
  """
  Return n times the nth number of every list in `values`,
  in a list of dictionaries.
  """
  intersect_list = []
  longest = max(map(len,values))
  for n in range(longest):
      # get the nth value if there is one, or just the last value
      nth_values = [l[n] if n<len(l) else l[-1] for l in values]
      intersect_list.append({key:nth_values})
  return intersect_list

dict_list = [{ 'key':10, 'values':[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]] }]
for d in dict_list:
  print(intersect(d['key'],d['values']))
```

It will give you the desired output:

```
[{10: [1, 3, 6]}, {10: [2, 4, 7]}, {10: [2, 5, 8]}, {10: [2, 5, 9]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well. Is "map" here the same as [Qmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmap.html#details) ?

Comment: The built-in function `map()` takes every item in `values` and applies the `len()` function to it. As a result you get a list of lengths and then take the biggest with `max()`

Comment: So `map()` is not the same as Qmap.

Comment: I should have said Qmap() in the Qmap class. Thanks for the precision, pretty useful! 

Here's an example from [this tutorial](http://fgallaire.flext.net/comprehension-de-liste-en-python-map-filter/): 

map(lambda x : 2*x, range(5)) == [2*x for x in range (5)]

>>>[0,2,4,6,8]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that should work, but note that your output cannot be a dictionary because you can’t have the same key show up more than once in a dictionary.

```
def intersection(key, values):
    return [(key, [L[i] if len(L) > i else L[-1] for L in values]) for i in range(max(map(len, values)))]

print(intersection(10, ([1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])))

# >>> [(10, [1, 3, 6]), (10, [2, 4, 7]), (10, [2, 5, 8]), (10, [2, 5, 9])]
```